# Python plot 3d surface drawing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function `F = 0.8*X+0.6*Y+0.9*Z` 
But my problem is X Y and Z related to each other. `X+Y+Z = 1`. The values and intervals should be like:

```
X = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Y = np.arange(0,(1-X),0.01)
Z = 1-(X+Y)
```

Could you please give a simple way of doing this in Python.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a surface plot in matplotlib your x, y and z arrays should be 2D arrays. If interval of your variables depends on each other, you can define your variables in terms of variables whose intervals is independent of each other like u and v in here.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
v = np.linspace(1, 0, 100)

x = np.outer(np.ones_like(u), v)
y = np.outer(v, u)
z = 1 - x - y
f = 0.8*x + 0.6*y + 0.9*z

norm = Normalize (f.min(), f.max())
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable()
m.set_array([])
fcolors = m.to_rgba(f)

ax.view_init(azim=45)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, norm=norm, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=fcolors, shade=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realize that I have two variable: x and y. z is basically 1-x-y. So I changed my function accordingly. From your code with simple modification I got the plot I want. 
Instead of using:

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, norm=norm, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=fcolors, shade=False) 

I used:

ax.plot_surface(x, y, f, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=fcolors, shade=False)

Comment: @OrhanAbar What you used produces a 3d plot (ie both color & height of points is f). Mine produces a 4D plot (ie height of points is z and their color is f)